# Chain Rule - $z''(t) = z'(t) \frac{dz'(t)}{dz}$

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics, chain-rule

all. This question may be a trivial answer, but I'm having trouble figuring this out. I'm taking a course in classical mechanics and I don't exactly see how the following equation is a result of the chain rule. My professor keeps saying "obviously" when calling on it, but I do not understand how it follows.

For a function $z=z(t)$, my professor claims the following:
$$ z''(t) = z'(t) \frac{dz'(t)}{dz} $$

How does this follow from the chain rule definition?

Thank you.

Comment: Write $z' = \mathrm d z/\mathrm d t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chain rule says that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}v}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
So in your case:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}z'}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}z'}{\mathrm{d}z}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$z''(t) = z'(t) \frac{dz'(t)}{dz}=z'(t) \frac{dz'(t)}{dt}\frac{dt}{dz(t)}=\frac{z'(t)z''(t)}{z'(t)}$$